# Process grep with pipe returns itself. How do I exclude it?

Tags: linux, bash

```
root@test:~# ps x | grep 'vsftpd'
  568 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd
28694 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto vsftpd
```

How can I exclude the self grep process itself? Also, how do I fetch the process Id (pid) given a part of the name of the process?

I am looking for something along the lines that it will give me pid given the name and excludes the self grep process.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I just realized that. Thank You.

Comment: More thorough answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/367921/how-to-prevent-ps-reporting-its-own-process)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The traditional way would be:

```
ps x | grep 'vsftpd'| grep -v grep
```

in which `grep -v expr` returns everything *not* matching `expr`

You can then use `awk` to extract the relevant field (the pid in your case)

```
ps x | grep 'vsftpd'| grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

(the `$2` corresponds to the relevant field/column)

Answer (score 10):

The usual trick is

```
ps x | grep '[v]sftpd'
```

Comment: The explanation: https://serverfault.com/a/367943